# htaccess rewrite works but how to redirect to the rewrite?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

Hey so I've searched up and down through the questions without finding the answer to what I'm looking for. If this is a dupe I apologize, please direct me to the answer.

So I've set up my htaccess so that if someone types in:

> www.example.com/menu

it loads the follow page "**www.example.com/page.php**".

The problem I'm facing is that if someone types in:

```
www.example.com/page.php
```

directly, it doesn't change the URL to "www.example.com/menu" and just remains showing as "www.example.com/page.php"

How can I make it so that if person types in either "www.example.com/page.php" or "www.example.com/menu" it will always show the url as "www.example.com/menu"?

here's my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^menu/?$ page.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your htaccess (in root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/page\.php [NC]
RewriteRule . /menu [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^menu$ /page.php [L]
```

Comment: perfect, that does exactly what I was looking for and using the 301 makes sense! Thank you :)

Comment: `\s` matches whitespaces characteres (space, tab, carriage, new line, etc). In the rule context, it is there to make sure user is trying to reach `/page.php` (in root level) and not `/some/subfolder/page.php`